# SEO - Google index a specific part of a link

Tags: seo, google-search

Google displays links to pages in its search results by taking all the text inside an  tag as the link. So this:

```
<a href="#">
   <span>1</span> This is a great story
</a>
```

displays in Google search results as:

**1 This is a great story**

Is there any way to tell Google to index a specific part of the link text, e.g.

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="dont-index-me">1</span>
   <span class="index-me">This is a great story</span>
</a>
```

So I can have just: **'This is a great story'**.

Or is the only option to change the markup:

```
<span>1</span> <a href="#">This is a great story</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Google will index an entire page's contents. there is no way to tell Google to ignore part of a page. There are black hat techniques, of course, but those just get you banned if you get caught and aren't worth the risk.

Answer (score 0):

just change the markup (2nd solution) ie. move it out of `<a>` tag